# Shiny app deployed in Azure Web Apps misforms when enabling authentication

Tags: authentication, shiny, containers, azure-web-app-service, azure-authentication

I have a containerized Shiny deployed and running as an Azure Web App.
Everything works fine. Click the links below for images.

[Link - App Correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eafXD.png)
[Link - Authentication disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/he8Dd.png)

But when I enable the authentification settings, the shiny app misforms and shows a malfunctioning app. This'toggeling' the option to 'enable' this happens. When I set it on 'disable', it runs smoothly again. Please look at the before and after picture. Please look at image 2 and 3

[Link - App misformed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wCon1.png)
[Link - Authentication enabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu7ln.png)

This really bothers me, because I intend to restrict access to my web apps.

Can someone help me? Perhaps I have to change some settings in the dockerfile or the app code.

Comment: Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the Authentication Providers. After that, you also need to choose a provider to take effect. For example, I configured the Azure Active Directory provider, then I choose "Log in with Azure Active Directory".

[image]

You can take a look at [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization).